# JSSOR transition is not working while autoplay

Tags: transition, jssor

Hi I have an issue while Autoplay is enable. During Autoplay no transition is toggled, images are simply exchanged - first disappears and second appears. 
I tried changing code and also CSS but it doent work. All I want is simple fade transition.

```
       var jssor_1_SlideshowTransitions = [{
                $Duration: 300,
                x: 0.3,
                $During: {
                    $Left: [0.3, 0.7]
                },
                $Easing: {
                    $Left: $Jease$.$InCubic,
                    $Opacity: $Jease$.$Linear
                },
                $Opacity: 2
            }
        ];

        var jssor_1_options = {
            $AutoPlay: 1,
            $FillMode: 5,
            $SlideshowOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorSlideshowRunner$,
                $Transitions: jssor_1_SlideshowTransitions,
                $TransitionsOrder: 1
            },
            $ArrowNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorArrowNavigator$
            },
            $ThumbnailNavigatorOptions: {
                $Class: $JssorThumbnailNavigator$,
                $SpacingX: 5,
                $SpacingY: 5
            },
            $SlideDuration: 200,
            $Idle: 5000
        };

        jssor_1_slider = new $JssorSlider$("jssor_1", jssor_1_options);
        jssor_1_slider.$HWA = false;
```

Warning - I am using Ajax for loading images - after I load them I fire

```
jssor_1_slider.$ReloadSlides(imageList);
```

Could this be an issue ?

Comment: Can I have the url of your page?

Comment: here you go - https://jazdectvoprekazdeho.sk/stajna?ID=5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked your page, you used `id` to specify css rules for the `slides` element.

On jssor slider initialize, it will resort dom hierarchy and clone some nodes, in this manner, `id` of some element will be lost.

Please always use `class` name to specify css rules for elements inside jssor slider.

```
<style>
    .imageList {
        cursor: default;
        position: relative;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 980px;
        height: 380px;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
</style>

<div data-u="slides" class="imageList" id="imageList">
```